# How value types differ from each other?

Tags: c#, struct, heap-memory, value-type

if size of two different structs are *exactly* same, how do they differ when they are being executed? there should be a little information about what type they are shouldn't be?

In stack, I could imagine this information can be stored without allocating extra memory (in some place like header or something). how ever In Heap, when struct is **not** boxed, does it allocate extra memory for its type information?

for example how `AnInt` differs from `int`, or other alike structs.

```
struct AnInt
{ 
    int _int;
}
```

Comment: The memory is managed for you. That's only [an implementation detail.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/)

Comment: but I'm curios how this is currently implemented. @ZoharPeled (also I want to know this mostly about heap, not stack)

Comment: Why would "size of two different structs are exactly same" matter?  And structs aren't getting 'executed'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It doesn't matter, its because I don't understand how they are managed so that is my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind that there's no inheritance for value types. This means that the *variables* for value types are enough to encode the type information. You know you're dealing with an `AnInt` because you're accessing it via an `AnInt` field, property or local variable.

In turn, this means that during compilation, the compiler knows exactly what methods, etc are the ones to call on that variable, and (again, because no inheritance) there's no virtual dispatch to consider.

Comment: so for fields of a class, there should be something that tells from here to there, it relates to AnInt and from there to there it relates to int. am I right?

Comment: Oh, so you are saying that this is completely formed in compiled code? so the method calls that are produced relates to those for AnInt struct?

Comment: as I read your answer multiple times it makes sense now, so its the compiler that compiles different code for different structs. and therefor type information is implied by compiled code.